# Poetry Update Fails: Unable to Find Installation Candidates for pyqt5-qt5 (5.15.11)

Tags: python, pip, pyqt5, dependency-management, python-poetry

**My Environment:**

- Operating System: [Windows 22H2]
- Python Version: [3.11]
- Poetry Version: [(version 1.7.1)]

**Attempted Solutions:**

- Clearing Poetry's cache
- Directly specified different versions of `pyqt5-qt5` in `pyproject.toml`.
- Checking network settings and proxy configurations

**Issue Description:**

I am encountering an issue when trying to update my Python project dependencies using Poetry. Specifically, Poetry is failing to find installation candidates for `pyqt5-qt5` version 5.15.11. Here are the steps I have tried which did not resolve the issue:

- Cleared Poetry's cache
- Confirmed that my network connection is stable
- Tried specifying different versions of `pyqt5-qt5`

Here is the output when I run `poetry update`:

```
(jsonrpc-py3.11) PS C:\PythonProject\pythonProject\jsonRPC> poetry update                                          
Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... (4.5s)

Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals

  • Installing pyqt5 (5.15.1): Failed

  ChefBuildError

  Backend subprocess exited when trying to invoke build_wheel
  
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\nbdhc\AppData\Roaming\pypoetry\venv\Lib\site-packages\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
      main()
    File "C:\Users\nbdhc\AppData\Roaming\pypoetry\venv\Lib\site-packages\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\nbdhc\AppData\Roaming\pypoetry\venv\Lib\site-packages\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 251, in build_wheel
      return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\nbdhc\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpcxilq025\.venv\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\api.py", line 46, in build_wheel
      project = AbstractProject.bootstrap('wheel',
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\nbdhc\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpcxilq025\.venv\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\abstract_project.py", line 87, in bootstrap
      project.setup(pyproject, tool, tool_description)
    File "C:\Users\nbdhc\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpcxilq025\.venv\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\project.py", line 586, in setup
      self.apply_user_defaults(tool)
    File "C:\Users\nbdhc\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpl4qbme9n\PyQt5-5.15.1\project.py", line 64, in apply_user_defaults
      super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
    File "C:\Users\nbdhc\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpcxilq025\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pyqtbuild\project.py", line 70, in apply_user_defaults
      super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
    File "C:\Users\nbdhc\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpcxilq025\.venv\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\project.py", line 237, in apply_user_defaults
      self.builder.apply_user_defaults(tool)
    File "C:\Users\nbdhc\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpcxilq025\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pyqtbuild\builder.py", line 69, in apply_user_defaults
      raise PyProjectOptionException('qmake',
  sipbuild.pyproject.PyProjectOptionException
  

  at ~\AppData\Roaming\pypoetry\venv\Lib\site-packages\poetry\installation\chef.py:164 in _prepare
      160│
      161│                 error = ChefBuildError("\n\n".join(message_parts))
      162│
      163│             if error is not None:
    → 164│                 raise error from None
      165│
      166│             return path
      167│
      168│     def _prepare_sdist(self, archive: Path, destination: Path | None = None) -> Path:

Note: This error originates from the build backend, and is likely not a problem with poetry but with pyqt5 (5.15.1) not supporting PEP 517 builds. You can verify this by running 'pip wheel --no-cache-dir --use-pep517 "pyqt5 (==5.15.1)"'.
```

Instead,it is normal when I install pyqt5 by pip:

```
(jsonrpc-py3.11) PS C:\PythonProject\pythonProject\jsonRPC> pip install pyqt5
Collecting pyqt5
  Using cached PyQt5-5.15.10-cp37-abi3-win_amd64.whl.metadata (2.2 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: PyQt5-sip<13,>=12.13 in c:\users\nbdhc\appdata\local\pypoetry\cache\virtualenvs\jsonrpc-1g8b7ov1-py3.11\lib\site-packages (from pyqt5) (12.13.0)
Collecting PyQt5-Qt5>=5.15.2 (from pyqt5)
  Using cached PyQt5_Qt5-5.15.2-py3-none-win_amd64.whl (50.1 MB)
Using cached PyQt5-5.15.10-cp37-abi3-win_amd64.whl (6.8 MB)
Installing collected packages: PyQt5-Qt5, pyqt5
Successfully installed PyQt5-Qt5-5.15.2 pyqt5-5.15.10
```

after my installation by pip, I fix my pyproject.toml's [tool.poetry.dependencies] to

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.11"
loguru = "^0.7.2"
sip = "^6.7.12"
pyqt5-sip = "^12.13.0"
pyqt5 = "=5.15.10"
pyqt5-qt  = "5.15.2"
```

the poetry's error are unchanged.

Additionally, running `pip wheel --no-cache-dir --use-pep517 "pyqt5 (==5.15.1)"` also results in errors:

```
$ pip wheel --no-cache-dir --use-pep517 "pyqt5 (==5.15.1)"
```

I have got error,too.

```
(jsonrpc-py3.11) PS C:\PythonProject\pythonProject\jsonRPC> pip wheel --no-cache-dir --use-pep517 "pyqt5 (==5.15.2)"
Collecting pyqt5==5.15.2
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /packages/28/6c/640e3f5c734c296a7193079a86842a789edb7988dca39eab44579088a1d1/PyQt5-5.15.2.tar.gz
  Downloading PyQt5-5.15.2.tar.gz (3.3 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 3.3/3.3 MB 4.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [25 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\nbdhc\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\jsonrpc-1g8b7oV1-py3.11\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\nbdhc\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\jsonrpc-1g8b7oV1-py3.11\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\nbdhc\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\jsonrpc-1g8b7oV1-py3.11\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 152, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          whl_basename = backend.build_wheel(metadata_directory, config_settings)
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\nbdhc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-r_utcu4y\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\api.py", line 46, in build_wheel
          project = AbstractProject.bootstrap('wheel',
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\nbdhc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-r_utcu4y\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\abstract_project.py", line 87, in bootstrap
          project.setup(pyproject, tool, tool_description)
        File "C:\Users\nbdhc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-r_utcu4y\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\project.py", line 586, in setup
          self.apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "C:\Users\nbdhc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-gtrn2jcu\pyqt5_d0e386869adb4ed9bf122a2a8aa3e1c7\project.py", line 63, in apply_user_defaults
          super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "C:\Users\nbdhc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-r_utcu4y\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pyqtbuild\project.py", line 70, in apply_user_defaults
          super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "C:\Users\nbdhc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-r_utcu4y\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\project.py", line 237, in apply_user_defaults
          self.builder.apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "C:\Users\nbdhc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-r_utcu4y\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pyqtbuild\builder.py", line 69, in apply_user_defaults
          raise PyProjectOptionException('qmake',
      sipbuild.pyproject.PyProjectOptionException
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Certainly,I tried use

```
$poetry cache clear --all pypl
```

but it doesn't work.

After installing with `pip`, I updated `pyproject.toml` as follows, but the issue persists:

```
pyqt5 = "=5.15.10"
```

```
$poetry update
Resolving dependencies... Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/66/f5/0a684b2b33b1f1dceaf894d4e8a105f523bb08003f81c89a91e509c5f854/PyQt5_Qt5-5.15.11-py3-none-macosx_10_13_x86_64.whl  99% 
Resolving dependencies... Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/66/f5/0a684b2b33b1f1dceaf894d4e8a105f523bb08003f81c89a91e509c5f854/PyQt5_Qt5-5.15.11-py3-none-macosx_10_13_x86_64.whl  99% Resolving dependencies... (43.5s)

Package operations: 0 installs, 1 update, 0 removals

  • Updating pyqt5-qt5 (5.15.2 -> 5.15.11): Failed

  RuntimeError

  Unable to find installation candidates for pyqt5-qt5 (5.15.11)

  at ~\AppData\Roaming\pypoetry\venv\Lib\site-packages\poetry\installation\chooser.py:73 in choose_for
       69│
       70│             links.append(link)
       71│
       72│         if not links:
    →  73│             raise RuntimeError(f"Unable to find installation candidates for {package}")
       74│
       75│         # Get the best link
       76│         chosen = max(links, key=lambda link: self._sort_key(package, link))
       77│

Cannot install pyqt5-qt5.
```

```
pyqt5 = "=5.15.2"
```

```
$poetry update
Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... (9.3s)

Package operations: 0 installs, 1 update, 0 removals

  • Downgrading pyqt5 (5.15.10 -> 5.15.2): Failed

  ChefBuildError

  Backend subprocess exited when trying to invoke build_wheel
  
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\nbdhc\AppData\Roaming\pypoetry\venv\Lib\site-packages\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
      main()
    File "C:\Users\nbdhc\AppData\Roaming\pypoetry\venv\Lib\site-packages\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\nbdhc\AppData\Roaming\pypoetry\venv\Lib\site-packages\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 251, in build_wheel
      return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\nbdhc\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpau4hqchz\.venv\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\api.py", line 46, in build_wheel
      project = AbstractProject.bootstrap('wheel',
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\nbdhc\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpau4hqchz\.venv\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\abstract_project.py", line 87, in bootstrap
      project.setup(pyproject, tool, tool_description)
    File "C:\Users\nbdhc\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpau4hqchz\.venv\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\project.py", line 586, in setup
      self.apply_user_defaults(tool)
    File "C:\Users\nbdhc\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpdh6v9hcw\PyQt5-5.15.2\project.py", line 63, in apply_user_defaults
      super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
    File "C:\Users\nbdhc\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpau4hqchz\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pyqtbuild\project.py", line 70, in apply_user_defaults
      super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
    File "C:\Users\nbdhc\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpau4hqchz\.venv\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\project.py", line 237, in apply_user_defaults
      self.builder.apply_user_defaults(tool)
    File "C:\Users\nbdhc\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpau4hqchz\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pyqtbuild\builder.py", line 69, in apply_user_defaults
      raise PyProjectOptionException('qmake',
  sipbuild.pyproject.PyProjectOptionException
  

  at ~\AppData\Roaming\pypoetry\venv\Lib\site-packages\poetry\installation\chef.py:164 in _prepare
      160│
      161│                 error = ChefBuildError("\n\n".join(message_parts))
      162│
      163│             if error is not None:
    → 164│                 raise error from None
      165│
      166│             return path
      167│
      168│     def _prepare_sdist(self, archive: Path, destination: Path | None = None) -> Path:

Note: This error originates from the build backend, and is likely not a problem with poetry but with pyqt5 (5.15.2) not supporting PEP 517 builds. You can verify this by running 'pip wheel --no-cache-dir --use-pep517 "pyqt5 (==5.15.2)"'.
```

**Summary of the Issue:**

Currently, I am able to successfully install `pyqt5` using `pip`, but I encounter issues when attempting to configure the same via `poetry`. This leads me to ponder whether the root cause of this problem lies in my specific configuration, the version of Python I am using, or some unknown aspects of `poetry` settings that I might not be aware of. I am looking for insights or solutions to effectively resolve this discrepancy between `pip` and `poetry`.

**Additional Context:**

- `pip install pyqt5` works without any issues.
- `poetry add pyqt5` or `poetry update` leads to errors, specifically in finding installation candidates or in building the wheel for `pyqt5`.
- My environment uses Python 3.11, and I have tried clearing `poetry`'s cache and directly specifying the version in `pyproject.toml`.
- The issue persists regardless of the version of `pyqt5` specified in `pyproject.toml`.

I have checked relevant documentation and other similar questions but haven't found a solution.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue, or does anyone have any suggestions on how to resolve it?

Thank you!

What I Tried:

Using pip: I successfully installed pyqt5 using pip without encountering any issues.

Using poetry:

I attempted to add pyqt5 using poetry add pyqt5, which resulted in errors related to finding installation candidates.
Running poetry update also led to similar issues, specifically errors in building the wheel for pyqt5.
I tried specifying different versions of pyqt5 in pyproject.toml, but the issue persisted.
Other Attempts:

Cleared Poetry's cache using poetry cache clear --all pypi.
Checked and confirmed network settings and proxy configurations.
What I Was Expecting:

I was expecting poetry to handle the installation of pyqt5 as smoothly as pip does. Specifically, I anticipated that poetry add or poetry update would successfully resolve and install the pyqt5 dependency without encountering errors, especially since the installation via pip was successful and straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

I solved installing the module using pip through poetry, i.e:

```
poetry run pip install pyqt5-qt5
```